# Multiple UIPickerView select first row programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swift4, uipickerview, pickerview

I find same case for one `pickerView`, I will say same words like below:

I have a `pickerView` that pops up when a `textField` is clicked inside. The user selects their location in the `pickerView`, and it's put into the `textField`.

When opening the `pickerView`, the slider is on the first element, but if I click the done button to minimize the `pickerView`, that no element is selected (i.e. you must scroll down and back up to select the first element)

I can make for a `textField` and a `pickerView`. But I have 3 textFields and 3 pickerViews. Can I do for every `pickerView`?

Below code block, works for one.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == yourTextField {
        self.yourPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        self.pickerView(yourPickerView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not set the text field with default text as the value in the first row of the picker? Should the text field be empty if the user never selects the text field?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri actually user have to select one becase second textfield items depends selected first item, and 3th depends 2th. What is your advice for this?

Comment: Have an extra picker item which says "-" (not selected yet) and set all the text fields to this. Do not let the user proceed unless he changes this value to a valid selection.

Answer (score 0):

How you described in comment, you want to start editing textField when user click to specific textField if text of previous textField isn't empty. So  use `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` delegate method like this:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == textField1 {
        return true
    } else if textField == textField2 && !textField1.isEmpty {
        return true
    } else if textField == textField3 && !textField2.isEmpty {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Then, when textField begin editing show specific pickerView

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == textField1 {
        // show pickerView1
    } else if textField == textField2 {
        // show pickerView2
    } else if textField == textField3 {
        // show pickerView3
    }
}
```

and then when user select row you want to change text in textField

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == pickerView1 {
        textField1.text = items1[row]
    } else if pickerView == pickerView2 {
        textField2.text = items2[row]
    } else if pickerView == pickerView3 {
        textField3.text = items3[row]
    }
}
```